# C Sharp GPA Calculator

Tags: c#

Im still fairly new to programming and need some help for C#. th problem is as follows... write an application that calculates a student’s GPA on a 4.0 scale. Grade point average (GPA) is calculated by dividing the total amount of grade points earned by the total amount of credit hours attempted.

For each hour, an A receives 4 grade points, a B receives 3 grade points, a C receives 2 grade points, and a D receives 1 grade point. by allowing the user to input any number of courses and associated grades And displaying the number of hours earned and the GPA.

so far this is what i got but i seem to be stuck. i believe it is with the scanner. i might be confusing it with java...

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   Console.WriteLine("Enter number of courses:");
   int course_count = input.Next();
   double grade_a = 4.0;
   double grade_b = 3.0;
   double grade_c = 2.0;
   double grade_d = 1.0;
   double total_grade_a = (course_count) * (grade_a);
   double total_grade_b = (course_count) * (grade_b);
   double total_grade_c = (course_count) * (grade_c);
   double total_grade_d = (course_count) * (grade_d);

   double gpa_a = total_grade_a / course_count;
   double gpa_b = total_grade_b / course_count;
   double gpa_c = total_grade_c / course_count;
   double gpa_d = total_grade_d / course_count;

   Console.WriteLine("The grading of A is" + gpa_a);
   Console.WriteLine("The grading of B is" + gpa_b);
   Console.WriteLine("The grading of C is" + gpa_c);
   Console.WriteLine("The grading of D is" + gpa_d);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that bothers you? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: "Grade point average (GPA) is calculated by dividing the total amount of grade points earned by the total amount of credit hours attempted. " So, `public void calculateGpa(double pointsEarned, double creditsAttempted) { return pointsEarned / creditsAttempted; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what the *Scanner* is doing there. If you want to take user input you can go like this.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a value.");
string reading = Console.ReadLine();
```

As for the computations in your program, it seems that you multiply the grades by *course_count* but afterwards divide it away...

Comment: i mixed it up with java which i took eons ago. thank you i'm going to give that a try

Comment: @Carlos Why the downvote?

Comment: @Carlos Also, if it helped you, please accept a reply as an answer. It rubs the ego nicely.   :)

Comment: Downvote? my apologies i'm still fairly new to the site. did i give you a bad rep by accident?

Comment: @Carlos Not sure. I assumed it was you and I thought you did so by mistake. It's back on zero now, so I might have been mistaken.  Have a nice coding!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused with Java. Use Console.ReadLine() to read user input.

Comment: Truee. i have added this thank you!